# Image swap won't work in Firefox but works in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to swap two images in two divs on click event, so that 22a.jpg ends up in div#second and 22b.jpg ends up in div#first, but every time I click the "swap" button I get this error in Firebug: **imgArray[2].src is undefined**. I tried to run the code in Chrome 17.0.963.2 and IE 8.0, and it works just fine with no errors. I'm using Firefox 11.0

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id = "first" class = "thumbnail">
        <img class = "thumbsize" src = "22a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id = "second" class = "thumbnail">
        <img class = "thumbsize" src = "22b.jpg" />
    </div>
    <input type = "button" id = "swap" value = "swap" />
</body>
```

JS

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("swap").onclick = function(){
        if(document.images){
            var imgArray = document.images;
            imgArray[2] = new Image();
            imgArray[2].src = imgArray[0].src;
            imgArray[0].src = imgArray[1].src;
            imgArray[1].src = imgArray[2].src;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`document.images`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.images) is readonly in Firefox ([link to specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-90379117)). You can create a new image, but you can't append it to the `document.images` array.

A better way to accomplish image swapping would look something like this:

```
document.getElementById("swap").onclick = function(){
    if(document.images){
        var imgArray = document.images;
        var tempSrc = imgArray[0].src;
        imgArray[0].src = imgArray[1].src;
        imgArray[1].src = tempSrc;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment and the code works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You only have two images in your HTML so imgArray[2] is not defined. Use a temp var to swap the other images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in some sort of [ready](http://makeagreatsite.com/javascript/how-execute-javascript-when-document-ready)-function?

Comment: Not yet. Gimme a min and I will get back to you asap

Comment: ok, you could try just saving the src in a variable, instead of creating a new Image. Just to give you some idea of what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button#swap').toggle(function() {
$("div#first > img").attr('src','22b.jpg');
$("div#second > img").attr('src','22a.jpg');
}, function() {
$("div#first > img").attr('src','22a.jpg');
$("div#second > img").attr('src','22b.jpg');
});
```

Would something like this work for you?